# Extjs Don't load Grid. PHP

Tags: php, json, extjs

Somebody would helpme with this code:Grid dont load infomations.
Below is the code I'm using, but the grid carries no information.
Extjs

```
             Ext.onReady(function(){
        var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        // store configs
        storeId: 'myStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data.php',
            reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'country',
            idProperty: 'total'
            }
        },

        //alternatively, a Ext.data.Model name can be given (see Ext.data.Store for an example)
        fields: ['name', 'area']
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Retorno',
    //store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    store:store,
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Area', dataIndex: 'area', flex: 1 }

    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

});
```

data.php here is the code with json code.

```
<?php 
print '{
    "total": 10,
    "country": [
        {
            "name": "CULTIV",
            "area": "6.96120082466223e-007"
        },
        {
            "name": "asdASdasd",
            "area": "123123123"
        }
    ]
}';
?>
```

Comment: You need to call `load` on the store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to set the store's `autoLoad` configuration to true.  If you do not set this attribute, then you will need to call the `load()` method of the store.

**Option 1**

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            // store configs
            storeId: 'myStore',
            autoLoad:true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'country'
                    //idProperty: 'total'
                }
            },

            //alternatively, a Ext.data.Model name can be given (see Ext.data.Store for an example)
            fields: ['name', 'area']
        });
```

**Option 2**

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            // store configs
            storeId: 'myStore',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'country'
                    //idProperty: 'total'
                }
            },

            //alternatively, a Ext.data.Model name can be given (see Ext.data.Store for an example)
            fields: ['name', 'area']
        });
        store.load();
```

[I created a working fiddle for a demonstration.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2qf)

Comment: Perfect my friend Great Thnk for help me.